Connect to a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS EC2 using Python
I'm a newbie in the field of AWS EC2 and PostgreSQL. I have been shared some access IDs of a PostgreSQL database hosted and I tested if I can connect to the database using TablePlus and successfully did that. A screenshot of that is,

It has these details for the database,


host = 127.0.0.1 (local)
Port = 5432 (default)
User : test
Password: *********(1)
Database = test_data
SSL mode: prefer


details of the EC2 server,


Server: aa.bbb.ccc.dd
Port: 23 (default)
user: starlord
Password:***********(2)


I want to connect to the database using python especially using psycopg2 and parmiko, I used the below code but didn't worked out. Can anyone guide me here?
aws_db_config.json
{
    "user": "test" (your_postgres_username),
    "password": "*********(1)" (your_postgres_password),
    "host": "aa.bbb.ccc.dd" (your_ec2_public_dns_or_ip),
    "port": "5432" (your_postgres_port),
    "database": "test_data",
    "sslmode": "prefer"  // or "disable" depending on your setup
}

my code,
import paramiko
import psycopg2
import json
import socket

def read_db_config_json(file_path):
    """Read database connection configuration from JSON file."""
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        db_config = json.load(file)
    return db_config

def create_ssh_tunnel(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_key_path, local_port, remote_host, remote_port):
    """Create an SSH tunnel to the PostgreSQL server."""
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ssh_host, port=ssh_port, username=ssh_user, key_filename=ssh_key_path)

    # Create a tunnel for the PostgreSQL connection
    transport = ssh.get_transport()
    tunnel = transport.open_channel(
        'direct-tcpip',
        (remote_host, remote_port),
        ('localhost', local_port)
    )
    return ssh, tunnel

def test_postgres_connection_via_ssh(config_file_path, ssh_config):
    """Connect to the PostgreSQL server via SSH tunneling and test the connection."""
    try:
        # Read the JSON config file
        db_config = read_db_config_json(config_file_path)

        # Create an SSH tunnel
        ssh, tunnel = create_ssh_tunnel(
            ssh_config['ssh_host'],
            ssh_config['ssh_port'],
            ssh_config['ssh_user'],
            ssh_config['ssh_key_path'],
            ssh_config['local_port'],
            db_config['host'],
            db_config['port']
        )

        # Update database config to use the local port
        db_config['host'] = 'localhost'
        db_config['port'] = ssh_config['local_port']

        # Establish the connection to PostgreSQL through the SSH tunnel
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_config)

        # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Query to get PostgreSQL version
        cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
        db_version = cursor.fetchone()
        print(f"Connected to PostgreSQL server: {db_version}\n")

        # Close the cursor and connection
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

        # Close the SSH tunnel
        tunnel.close()
        ssh.close()

    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Error connecting to the PostgreSQL database: {error}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Provide the path to your aws_db_config.json
    # SSH configuration for the EC2 instance
    ssh_config = {
        'ssh_host': 'aa.bbb.ccc.dd',
        'ssh_port': 23,  # default SSH port
        'ssh_user': 'starlord',
        'ssh_key_path': r'./saved.pem',
        'local_port': 5432  # local port for the tunnel
    }
    test_postgres_connection_via_ssh('aws_db_config.json', ssh_config)

But this is throwing me error,
Error connecting to the PostgreSQL database: encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key

what's the best way to connect and test the connection?

Read the error message.  Or at least show it to us.

If you left (your_postgres_username) and the other (...) strings in aws_db_config.json that would be a problem.

@jjanes I've added the error I'm encountering.

@AdrianKlaver no that's just for demonstration purpose to show exactly which of the variables I'm using where.

That looks like an error setting up the ssh tunnel, nothing to do with PostgreSQL itself.  You generally shouldn't catch an error if you aren't going to do anything meaningful with it, just let it get thrown naturally.

Check the format of key used to connect through your ssh tunnel, the message state that it expect an OPENSSH format that begins with (-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----):
RSA Key Format: Traditional format for SSH keys (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----).
OPENSSH Key Format: A newer format for private keys (-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----).
if you need to convert it use ssh-keygen or putty.
